# Any ideas on how to solve Duplicate class with android jetified?

Tags: java, android, gradle, gradlew

I'm getting the following error when trying to build an android application with two third-party dependencies.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class a.a.a.a found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.a$a found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.b found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.c found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.d found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.e found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.f found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.k.a found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.l.a found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.l.b found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.m.a found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.m.a$a found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.m.b found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.m.c found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class a.a.a.m.d found in modules jetified-pos-comm-sdk-1.2.2-runtime (net.geidea.sdk:pos-comm-sdk:1.2.2) and jetified-stario10-1.0.0-runtime (com.starmicronics:stario10:1.0.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

Does anyone know how solve this issue?

I have a minimal android project if anyone can help me solve this: https://github.com/mohammedhammoud/geidea-stario10-duplicate-class-deps-error

Comment: Those dependencies look commercial and don't have public documentation. In my experience contacting the developers of the sdk/libraries is your best bet.

Comment: Also if your project has minimum sdk above 21, you shouldn't need to enable multidex explicitly, it should be enabled by default.

Comment: This is now solved. I contacted the maintainers of the libraries, they added flattenpackagehierarchy to proguard which solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You should add your comment as an answer, and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. I contacted the maintainers of the libraries, they added flattenpackagehierarchy to proguard which solved it.